# How can I select a field that used in GROUP BY statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, case

I want to select a field that I use in GROUP BY statement. 
My statement is something like this

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN A.kcu_id is null THEN A.id ELSE A.kcu_id END) as id,
    ...
GROUP BY
    (CASE WHEN A.kcu_id is null THEN A.id ELSE A.kcu_id END),
    performance_cabang.tahun
```

It fails because

> Error column "a.kcu_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I know that I must use that column in `GROUP BY`, but the `GROUP BY` statement that I use is using `CASE` function. I must use `CASE` function because I don't want to group empty id

Sample data :

```
---------------------------------------
| Id | Name  | Kcu_id | Price         |
---------------------------------------
| 1  | Kcu_1 |        | 2000          |
---------------------------------------
| 2  | Kcp_2 | 1      | 3000          |
---------------------------------------
```

I want the GROUP BY to result something like this

```
------------------------------
| Id | Name  | Price         |
------------------------------
| 1  | Kcu_1 | 5000          |
------------------------------
```

Fyi, Kcu_id is foreign key with 'id' in this same table

Comment: Tip: you don't need `CASE WHEN foo IS NULL`, instead just use `COALESCE`.

Comment: Can you provide sample data??

Comment: What you've written should work. Check that you are not referencing to `A.kcu_id` somewhere else in the list of columns in `SELECT`.

Comment: Just try this : - http://hastebin.com/odokucaxor.sql

Comment: Ah, I forget, yes.. yes, it works now, it doesn't work because i referencing A.kcu_id somewhere else in the sql, thanks @VladimirBaranov

Answer (score -1):

You don't want to use case function inside the 'GroupBy' function.

for eg:

SELECT
    (CASE WHEN A.kcu_id is null THEN A.id ELSE A.kcu_id END) as id,
    ...
GROUP BY
    A.kcu_id ,
    performance_cabang.tahun

You only need to use the fields in group by